# Writing combobox items to a file?

Tags: delphi, combobox, pascal

I've created a `TComboBox` that displays a drop down menu of a list of about 30 items.
When I select one item from the list in the program it is not written to my file however the other `TEdit` parts of the form are.
How do I go about assigning these items from the combobox to a string in order to write them to a file?
I'm clueless as to how to write the procedure which will do this as you can see it isn't specified below

```
unit AddStudent2;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils, FileUtil, Forms, Controls, Graphics, Dialogs, StdCtrls,
  ExtCtrls, ActnList;

CONST
  Filename = 'c:\COMP4\StudentList.txt';

type
  NewStudent = Record
          Name : string [10];
          Surname : string [10];
          TutorGroup : string [10];
          CareerPreference : string [10];
          ID : Integer;
  end;

StudentList = file of NewStudent;

  { TAddStudent }
  TAddStudent = class(TForm)
    AddStudentButton: TButton;
    CareerList: TComboBox;    //item i need help with//
    Label1: TLabel;
    LabelChecker: TLabel;
    StudentForenameEntry: TEdit;
    StudentTutorGroup: TLabel;
    StudentSurnameEntry: TEdit;
    StudentSurname: TLabel;
    StudentName: TLabel;
    StudentPreferredSubject1: TLabel;
    StudentTutorGroupEntry: TEdit;
    procedure ButtonAddStudentClick(Sender : TObject);
    end;

{StudentForm}
var
  StudentForm: TAddStudent;
  StudentRec : NewStudent;
  StudentFile : StudentList;
  MyList : TStringList;
  i : integer;
  TextDrop : String;

implementation
uses
  StudentAddNotifier, SubjectError;
{$R *.lfm}



Procedure TAddStudent.ButtonAddStudentClick(Sender : TObject);
begin
  AssignFile(StudentFile,'c:\COMP4\v2\rsd\sa\COMP44\StudentList.txt');
  StudentRec.Name:= StudentForenameEntry.Text;
  StudentRec.Surname:= StudentSurnameEntry.Text;
  StudentRec.TutorGroup:= StudentTutorGroupEntry.Text; 
  begin
  begin
   StudentRec.CareerPreference  :=     CareerList.Items[CareerList.ItemIndex] ;
    reset(StudentFile);
  seek(StudentFile,System.FileSize(StudentFile));
  write(StudentFile,StudentRec);
  CloseFile(StudentFile);      
    reset(StudentFile);
    seek(StudentFile,System.FileSize(StudentFile));  
    write(StudentFile,StudentRec);
    CloseFile(StudentFile);  
    StudentForm.Close;
    Form3.show; 
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Post the relevant code, please.

Comment: Code samples are very important. They help to understand the problem and they also prove, you have a basic understanding of the topic you ask about.

Comment: Code sample does not compile, type `SchoolRecordStudent` not defined. If your file does not exist, you must create it before writing. You don't mention what the problem is. Not working is not an appropriate description.

Comment: Please ask a new question to ask a new question. A question is not a scratch pad where you progress your project.

Answer (score 1):

Just access the `TComboBox.Items` by the `TComboBox.ItemIndex` if the `ItemIndex` is not equal to  -1. (-1 indicates no item is selected.)

```
var
  CareerItem: string;
begin
  if Career.ItemIndex <> -1 then
  begin
    CareerItem := CareerList.Items[ComboBox1.ItemIndex];
    // Do whatever with CareerItem
  end;
end;
```

Comment: would the above answer also be the carry the same sort of principle when adding strings from a file to items in a TListBox to be displayed

Comment: No, but that would be a different question and should be asked in a new post. :-) The question here has been answered. StackOverflow is a question/answer site, where it's one question that can be answered per post. The code is totally different for adding to a ListBox or ComboBox, and how you do so depends on if you're adding single items or all of the items from the file at once to replace what's already there.

Comment: L.Lowry: if you find this answer helpful, you should consider marking it Accepted (by clicking the check mark beside it). Only you can do that, and I think it's appropriate (it's important to recognize good answers).

Comment: Thanks for the code but the problem was located elsewhere as my file path had changed youve done pretty much the same as what i have

Comment: @User3545: It answered the question asked here, which was "How do I go about assigning these items from the combobox to a string in order to write them to a file?".

Comment: actually you are right didnt notice this line if Career.ItemIndex <> -1 that was the main issue thanks for the help

Comment: @User3545: If this answers your question, you should accept it so that others know it's been resolved for you. See [this help center page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Asside from using the `ItemIndex` you can also use the `Text` property to get the currently selected item: `StudentRec.CareerPreference := Careerlist.Text;`
Note that if the user typed something in the combobox that you will get that text, so you might want to disable that by setting the combobox to read only.